# Read __attribute__((annotate("MyAnnotation"))) at runtime

Tags: objective-c

I would like to mark a property for being injected with a value like follows…

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<MyDownloadingManagerDelegate> \
   injectedDownloadManager __attribute__((annotate("DependenceInjection:inject")));
```

Is there any way to read this annotation at runtime?

I have tried the following without success.

```
objc_property_t* properties = class_copyPropertyList([instance class], &count);
for (int i = 0; i < count ; i++)
{
    objc_property_t property = properties[i];
    const char* propertyAttrs = property_getAttributes(property);
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible. they are for compile time only

Comment: libextobjc have some hack allow you annotate property: https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc/blob/experimental/extobjc/EXTAnnotation.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__attribute__`s are compiler annotations; with a few exceptions (`constructor`/`destructor` off the top of my head) they have no effect on runtime behavior. They definitely have no interaction with the ObjC runtime's encodings or other internal bookkeeping.

What I would suggest for your case is creating a protocol with a class method which each conforming class implements to return a list of its injectable properties. Precedent for this idea is set by [`+keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002299-SW4).